# Spring controller invoked 2 times

Tags: java, spring

I have my project with SpringBoot 1.5.1 gradle.

I need to response with pdf file with "OK" or some other statuses.

So problem is when I request with "Postman" code invokes 2 times.
              when I request with "curl" code invokes 1 time.

Obviously I want to invoke it 1 time.

I have an application class with:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
}
```

And my controller with:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/report/{reportTemplate:.+}", method = POST)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity createReport(HttpEntity<List<ParametersEntity>> httpEntity,
                                   @PathVariable String reportTemplate) throws IOException {

byte[] data = ...;// my data
return ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .contentLength(data.length)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF)
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=output.pdf")
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE))
                .body(data);

    }
```

`createReport` is in `@RestController` class.

Also I have `application.properties` file in my src/main/resources/

```
server.port: 10500
management.port: 10501
management.address: 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: What's your Postman version ? It seems to be a known issue on its side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks OK. Nothing wrong with it.

If you are in `DEBUG` mode when invoking the request from the `POSTMAN` it may confuse it and send the request for a second time. I gues it depends on some configurations. But while you have no problems with `CURL` you must search the problem in `POSTMAN` probably not your code.

Comment: PS: I would have left this as a comment but I do not have enough reputation to do so.